# `cdk deploy` adding a api and event rule construct info to std out - how to stop this?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

After some recent updates to AWS CDk, Ive seen there is a lot more output when using the `cdk deploy` command.

Of note, i see that any of our `event.Rule(...)` constructs cause an output in the terminal, something like this:

```
{
  scope: <ref *1> Rule {
    node: ConstructNode { host: [Circular *1], _actualNode: [Node] },
    stack: NestedStack {
      node: [ConstructNode],
      _missingContext: [],
      _stackDependencies: {},
      templateOptions: {},
      _logicalIds: [LogicalIDs],
      account: '#########',
      region: 'us-east-1',
      environment: 'aws://#########/us-east-1',
      terminationProtection: undefined,
      _stackName: 'StackName',
      tags: [TagManager],
      artifactId: undefined,
      templateFile: 'NestedStackName.nested.template.json',
      _versionReportingEnabled: undefined,
      synthesizer: [NestedStackSynthesizer],
      _parentStack: [Stack],
      parameters: {},
      resource: [CfnStack],
      nestedStackResource: [CfnStack],
      _contextualStackName: '${Token[TOKEN.2216]}',
      _contextualStackId: '${Token[TOKEN.2217]}',
      [Symbol(@aws-cdk/core.DependableTrait)]: [Object]
    },
    env: { account: '#########', region: 'us-east-1' },
    _physicalName: undefined,
    _allowCrossEnvironment: false,
    physicalName: '${Token[TOKEN.3075]}',
    targets: [],
    eventPattern: {},
    _xEnvTargetsAdded: Set(0) {},
    description: undefined,
    scheduleExpression: 'cron(4 * * * ? *)',
    ruleArn: '${Token[TOKEN.3078]}',
    ruleName: '${Token[TOKEN.3080]}',
    [Symbol(@aws-cdk/core.DependableTrait)]: { dependencyRoots: [Array] }
  },
  action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction',
  principal: <ref *2> ServicePrincipal {
    grantPrincipal: [Circular *2],
    principalAccount: undefined,
    assumeRoleAction: 'sts:AssumeRole',
    service: 'events.amazonaws.com',
    opts: {}
  },
  sourceArn: '${Token[TOKEN.3078]}'
}
```

(cleaned up of identifying info)

There is also our RestAPI's gettin this as well.

Now, we include a lot of our own print/stdout statements in our stack to track some useful information in our CodeBuild logs that are utilizing cdk deploy to quickly deploy test environments, so I cannot just >dev/null this command. However this also adds a lot of spam to our logs and to the codebuild console when we're trying to diagnose an issue with a deployment

I have double checked that none of our print statements are including the actual construct in the print statement f-string,

we use the following for our cdk deploy

```
cdk deploy Stack\* -c some_variables=variable --require-approval never --force --outputs-file ./cdk-outputs.json
```

but it doesn't matter what flags we use - even just `cdk synth` will output it.

Ive tried `cdk deploy Stack\* --debug False` but that doesnt seem to do anything (no surprise) and also tried varying uses of the `-v` flag but again - nothing good there (again as well - no surprise as they both are intended to go the opposite direction)

Any insight to help clean these up would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I could not replicate this output with a Stack with a Rule Construct (v2.20 Python).  The presence of unresolved Tokens in the output is consistent with it being written pre-synth to STDOUT.

Comment: Thats what I thought too, but i cannot find any print or other statements that would be causing this. Thanks for trying anyways

Comment: Ive since gone through and removed all print statements for a test run, and the values continue to show.

Could this be related to the ` --outputs-file` flag? Or similarly the `CfnOutput` functionality? (even though we are only outputting attributes that resolve to strings ...)

Comment: I don't think so.  The printing logic in `cdk deploy` is [quite strightforward](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/8c8b6b68b98e090580357172c247267ce92f2668/packages/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts#L243-L270).  The output you are seeing must be being produced upstream of deploy, either before or during synth.